# C# Web Service - Web Service accepts XElement, but test program expects XmlElement

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, linq, web-services

I have a weird issue that I'm not at all sure how to fix. I have a web service, written in C#, that has multiple methods that all accept parameters of type `XElement`. In order to test the web service I've created, I created a simple console application in Visual Studio and made a reference to this web service. Using the soap client that's already created, I put a line of code in calling my method that has the following method header: `public string SendTicket(XElement xmlTicket)`. That line is like so: `testref.SendTicket(fullXML)` with `fullXML` being of type `XElement`. After inserting that line of code, I get a design-time error that says `Argument 1: cannot convert from System.Xml.Linq.XElement to System.Xml.XmlElement`. I can't for the life of me figure out why this conversion is even happening.

The web service is clearly coded to accept an `XElement` parameter, but when I try to test it with my own console application, it says that the method(s) accept, instead, `System.Xml.XmlElement`.

I can provide the code and/or my `using` declarations on request...I just can't figure this out! I've even removed and readded the reference only to see that it just defaults to `XmlElement` instead of `XElement`.

Comment: Well presumably the *client* piece is being generated separately, right? So how are you generating that? I don't know whether the SOAP generator has any options to generate client code using LINQ to XML...

Comment: @JonSkeet yep -- I am generating that via right-clicking Service References and hitting Add Service Reference and then inputting the URL at which my web service is hosted. I suppose you could be correct about the SOAP client not being able to handle LINQ to XML, but I find that odd. If that's the case -- oh well, I'm just going to have to test using XmlElement.